# Expand macro before it is undefed

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

I have a macro that I define at the beginning of a header and then undef at the end. However that macro (I'll call it `foo`) depends on another macro (I'll call it `test`). I was wondering whether I can remember the value to which `foo` expands. My first idea was the following, which obviously doesn't work:

```
#define foo test
#define bar foo
#undef foo

...
bar
...
```

Is there a way to make so that in the end `bar` expands to `test`?

Comment: AFAIK you cannot do this. SOund like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: `#define bar test`?

Comment: @MichaelWalz I can figure out some way to solve my actual problem. I am actually interested in the answer of this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't.

Macros are expanded only at the moment they are inserted into the programming token stream. They are not expanded in the `#define` preprocessing directive.